# import error while using db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I get an Import error while importing the `thermos.py` module in my `models.py` module.

- C:\Users\sys\Thermos\thermos\thermos.py
- C:\Users\sys\Thermos\thermos\models.py

Here is the relevant part of the `thermos.py` module.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'thermos.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And, here is the relevant part of the `models.py` module.

```
from datetime import datetime
from thermos import db
```

Here is the image of the error I receive in CMD:

[image: Here is the image of the error I receive in CMD]

Kindly let me know what needs to be done to fix this issue.

Comment: apologies for the poor draft....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can't decide if you're trying to import from the folder, or the file named `thermos`

You can rename

`C:\Users\sys\Thermos\thermos\thermos.py`

To

`C:\Users\sys\Thermos\thermos\__init__.py`

This makes the `thermos` directory [a package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#package) with the `db` variable that can be used with an import

```
from . import db
```

Comment: Below is my root directory.
Thermos\thermos
     |
    |- static
    |
    |- templates
    |
    |- __init__.py
      |- forms.py
    |- models.py
    |- thermos.py.. I already have an empty __init__.py, if that is what you were referring to... I believe the problem is inside the thermos.py module

Comment: I can't read the formatting there, but I'm saying that the init module doesn't need to be empty if you want the app and db to be shared throughout the package